# Semi-Transparent JButton: Objects appear in Background

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton, transparency

I got a Problem: I started to make a nicer looking extension of Swing- JButton. 
One of the remaining problems: Whenever I set it "Semi-Transparent" (like `this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100,90));`) the optic becomes weird: every time I hover my mouse over the Button the last Swing-Element with a String (like a JRadioButton or a JCheckBox) I hovered over will appear in the background.

My current Button:

```
private boolean transparent;
private boolean drawImage;
private final int width;
private final int height;
int marginWidth=15;
int marginHeight=15;

public MyButton(String text, String command){
    super(text);
    this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    this.setOpaque();
    this.setActionCommand(command);

    this.setBackground(ParameterPool.COLOR_BACKGROUND_SECOND);
    this.setBorder(null);

    this.width = (int) this.getPreferredSize().getWidth()+marginWidth;
    this.height = (int) this.getPreferredSize().getHeight()+marginHeight;

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.width, this.height));

}


public void setTransparent() {
    this.transparent = true;
    this.setOpaque(false);
}

public void setOpaque() {
   this.transparent = false;
   this.setOpaque(true);
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 


    g2d.fillRoundRect(0,0,width,height,18,18); 

    g2d.setColor(Color.darkGray); 
    g2d.drawRoundRect(0,0,width, height,18,18); 

    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false); 
    Rectangle2D r = getFont().getStringBounds(getText(), frc);
    float xMargin = (float)(width-r.getWidth())/2; 
    float yMargin = (float)(height-getFont().getSize())/2; 
    g2d.drawString(getText(), xMargin, (float)getFont().getSize() + yMargin); 
    this.setSize(width, height);
}

public JPanel inTransparentPanel(){
    JPanel ret = new JPanel();
    ret.setOpaque(false);
    ret.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    ret.add(this);
    return ret;
}
```

One more thing: I also tried this without overriding the paintComponent(...)-Method. No effect.

Comment: `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; ..` should be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){ sper.pintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; ..` For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) `this.setSize(width, height);` don't do anything within a paint method that might trigger a repaint, as that will cause an infinite loop. 2) `ret.setDoubleBuffered(true);` since `ret` is a `JPanel` it is double buffered by default.

Comment: Thank you all for your help,
- super is totally not what I want
- setSize is totally wrong, thanks

Nevertheless this seems not to be the problem. I figured it out like mentioned below.

Comment: Swing doesn't like opaque components which have alpha based components, so be very careful. Failing to call `super.paintComponent` is a very risky move and shouldn't be modifying the state of the component from within the `paint` method is a bad idea and generally, you shouldn't be using `setSize`, you're going to be constantly fighting the layout manager which is going to start causing unneeded repaints and other possible issues, generally speaking, IMHO you have a big of issues which have the potential to cause a never ending series of random problems

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just fixed this problem "by accident": I figured out that one of the Panels arround that buttons still was a java awt Pane. Never thought of that as a problem.

Comment: Yes, mixing light (Swing) and heavy (AWT) weight components was historically a problem. Oracle supposedly fixed it, though I don't know of any Swing aficionado who now recommends mixing the two.

Comment: Oh, and almost forgot to mention. That problem is not something that we could know from the above source, but would have quickly identified with a [mcve]. But of course, you probably would have discovered the problem in the process of making an MCVE ;)